# Use StyleCop in Rider

Tags: code-formatting, stylecop, rider

I have some questions:

1. Is is possible to use StyleCop.Analyzers is Unity Rider project? Or unity project is not .NET core project?
2. Where should i put Settings.StyleCop file to override standart rules?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [script](https://github.com/vad710/UnityEngineAnalyzer/issues/27#issuecomment-399764272) to Editor folder
2. Add dlls with custom analysers to "RoslynAnalyzers" folder in the solution root.

Follow full discussion here https://github.com/vad710/UnityEngineAnalyzer/issues/27